# How Do I Change An Existing DynamoDB Table's Pricing Model in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

**Problem:** AWS Amplify has built all my tables with the "On-Demand" pricing model.

How can I change "On-Demand" to provisioned and set the read and write capacity units?

**Requirements:**

1. Cannot lose data in the table
2. Has do be done following the infrastructure as code principals, where I run `amplify push apiName` to push the new changes

Comment: Is this a bad question? Help me improve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the billing mode of your DynamoDB table directly using the Amplify CLI, however you can override the base functionality by extending the Amplify Cloudformation stack with the use of CDK (Cloud Development Kit).

With the Storage Module you can run `amplify override storage` to create an override.ts file to add custom CDK Typescript code to override the base functionality of your Storage resources created via the Amplify CLI.

This will append these changes to your existing Amplify Cloudformation stack and apply these changes when you run `amplify push` to provision your stack.

For your DynamoDB tables you can customize the following properties of the `dynamoDBTable` and override the changes of the attributes you need. For example to update the read and write capacity you would override the `ProvisionedThrought` property and update the Read and write capacity units value to your desired amount. Below is an example of TypeScript code which shows this.

```
import { AmplifyDDBResourceTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyDDBResourceTemplate) {
  resources.dynamoDBTable.billingMode = 'PROVISIONED'
}
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/override/#customize-amplify-generated-s3-resources